# BOOTSTRAP 3: Custom Navbar Toggle Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have red lines between my menu option on my Bootstrap 3 navbar as can be seen in the image below:

[image]

This is achieved using the following code:

```
<style>

    .navbar-nav li{
      position: relative
  }
  .navbar-nav li:after{
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: -2px;
      width:2px;
      height: 50%;
      top: 25%;
      background: red
  }
    .navbar-nav li:before{
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      width:2px;
      height: 50%;
      top: 25%;
      background: red
  }

</style>
```

The problem I have is that when the browser window size drops below a width of 768 the toggle button kicks in and once selected shows an ugly scroll bar at the bottom of the drop down as seen below:
[image]

When I scroll right all it shows is the red bar as per below:[image]

I have tried various options and it seems the solution is tied to the media width of the page but I just can't quite get it all working.  Ideally I would NOT show the red bars when the bootstrap toggle kicks in.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the red lines within a media query. There most likely is a media query defined already since you use bootstrap.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav li:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: -2px;
    width:2px;
    height: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    background: red
  }
  .navbar-nav li:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width:2px;
    height: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    background: red
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use

```
@media (max-width:768px) { 
  .navbar-nav {
    overflow-x:hidden;
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.  I did upvote yours but saw the answer below first.  I can also relate to how the one below works but do appreciate your swift response.